# AJAX Post to Update List in View

Tags: ajax, list

I have a List in my model. The view is bound to the model. I am trying to populate the List through ajax. And then I have a 'submit' button on the form which should submit the entire model. While submitting the entire model, the list value is 'null'??

I am getting the response data from the controller through Json. The response data is not bound to the model.

```
<table id="tblTable" style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid" >
        <tr style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Col1")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.Label("Col2")
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tbody>
        @if (Model != null && Model.Operations!= null && Model.Operations.Count > 0)
        {
            foreach (var item in Model.Operations)
            {
                <tr style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
                    <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col1)
                    </td>
                    <td style="border-width:1px;border-style:solid">
                        @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Col2)
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        }
       </tbody>
    </table>
```

My controller that responds to teh ajax request:

```
[HttpPost]
    public JsonResult UploadFile(HttpPostedFileBase file, Model model)
    {
         //extract file contents into the operations list
    model.Operations = new List<Operations>();
    model.Operations.Add(blah..blah)
      return Json(model);
    }
```

Issue is, I have to populate the list via ajax, but post the complete model along with the ajax-retrieved data.

Update: JS CODE:

$(document).ready(function () {

```
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({

        dataType: 'json',
        url: '/Summary/UploadFile',
        autoUpload: true,

        done: function (e, data) {
            var operations = data.result.Operations;
            var tbl = $('#tblTable');
            $.each(operations, function (key, val) {                                    
                $('<tr><td>' + val.col1 + '</td>' + '<td>' +               
                  val.col2 + '</td><tr>').appendTo(tbl);
            });          
        }
    }).on('fileuploadprogressall', function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        $('.progress .progress-bar').css('width', progress + '%');
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you include your JavaScript code and a sample JSON response in your post?

Comment: Isn't there anyone who knows how to populate a list model attribute via ajax?